# Python: Getting file modification times with greater resolution than a second

Tags: python, windows, macos, filesystems, timestamp

`os.path.getmtime()` and `os.stat()` seem to return values in whole seconds only.

Is this the greatest resolution possible on either a Windows or OSX file system, or is there a way of getting greater resolution on file times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The documentation for os.stat()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat) has a note that says:

> The exact meaning and resolution of
>   the st_atime, st_mtime, and st_ctime
>   members depends on the operating
>   system and the file system. For
>   example, on Windows systems using the
>   FAT or FAT32 file systems, st_mtime
>   has 2-second resolution, and st_atime
>   has only 1-day resolution. See your
>   operating system documentation for
>   details.

On for instance [Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724284(VS.85).aspx), the FILETIME structure used to represent file times uses a 100-nanosecond resolution. I would expect Python to "know" this, and give you the best possible resolution. Is it possible that you're using files on a FAT filesystem?

Comment: The files were written on an OSX file system, and only showed greater resolution on Windows when modified on the Windows system

Answer (score 5):

HFS+ (used by OS X) has a date resolution of [one second](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus).

Comment: The Wikipedia article you link to no longer says anything about the time resolution of HFS+. However, I found confirmation in John Siracusa's Lion review. http://arstechnica.com/apple/2011/07/mac-os-x-10-7/12/

Comment: I think the only statement was ever the "Date resolution" in the infobox, which is still there. Not the best source... There's also [the HFS+ technote](http://web.archive.org/web/20041115093148/http://developer.apple.com/technotes/tn/tn1150.html#HFSPlusDates), though that may be pretty outdated now—for instance, Mac OS X somehow has a way to store modification dates past 2040.

Answer (score 0):

As documented in [the Python `os` module](http://docs.python.org/library/os), it is a portable interface to OS-specific functionality. Depending on what platform you're running on, you will get different behaviour.

Specifically, the modification time returned by `stat` calls is dependent on the filesystem where the files reside. For example, for entries in a FAT filesystem, the finest resolution for modification time is 2 seconds. Other filesystems will have different resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 os.stat() contains st_atime_ns, st_ctime_ns, st_mtime_ns properties with nano seconds resolution, depends on the time-structure saved by the file system. see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html