# Accuracy of stat mtime in Windows

Tags: python, windows, filemtime

Have an example piece of (Python) code to check if a directory has changed:

```
import os

def watch(path, fdict):
    """Checks a directory and children for changes"""
    changed = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
       for f in files:
           abspath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, f))
           new_mtime = os.stat(abspath).st_mtime
           if not fdict.has_key(abspath) or new_mtime > fdict[abspath]:
               changed.append(abspath)
               fdict[abspath] = new_mtime
    return fdict, changed
```

But the accompanying unittest randomly fails unless I add at least a 2 second sleep:

```
import unittest
import project_creator
import os
import time


class tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        os.makedirs('autotest')
        f = open(os.path.join('autotest', 'new_file.txt'), 'w')
        f.write('New file')

    def tearDown(self):
        os.unlink(os.path.join('autotest', 'new_file.txt'))
        os.rmdir('autotest')

    def test_amend_file(self):
        changed = project_creator.watch('autotest', {})
        time.sleep(2)
        f = open(os.path.join('autotest', 'new_file.txt'), 'a')
        f.write('\nA change!')
        f.close()
        changed = project_creator.watch('autotest', changed[0])
        self.assertEqual(changed[1], [os.path.abspath(os.path.join('autotest', 'new_file.txt'))])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Is stat really limited to worse than 1 second accuracy? (Edit: apparently so, with FAT)
Is there any (cross platform) way of detecting more rapid changes?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943503/python-getting-file-modification-times-with-greater-resolution-than-a-second.

Comment: Thanks, that answers the first question (my google-fu was obviously lacking when I searched earlier). I'm still interested in alternative methods (if there are any).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *proper* way is to watch a directory instead of polling for changes.

Check out [FindFirstChangeNotification Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417%28VS.85%29.aspx).
 [Watch a Directory for Changes](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html) is a Python implementation.

If directory watching isn't accurate enough then probably the only alternative is to intercept file systems calls.

Comment: This is something I looked into, but as stated above I need this code to run cross platform (XP and Ubuntu specifically). I may have to give up and vary the mechanism based on os.

Answer (score 1):

Watchdog:
http://packages.python.org/watchdog/quickstart.html

Is a good project to have some multi-platform changes notification.

Comment: Answering to myself, I just discovered that QT does it too, http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfilesystemwatcher.html Then you can use pyqt or pyside for a nice python interface.

Answer (score 0):

if this were linux, i'd use inotify. there's apparently a windows inotify equivalent - the java [jnotify library](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/) has implemented it - but i don't know if there's a python implementation